# Is there concurrent & self-expiring & ordered hash map in java

Tags: java, dictionary, guava

I'm using `ConcurrentHashMap` from google guava (via MapMaker), but that implementation isn't ordered.
There is `ConcurrentSkipListMap` in google guava, but that structure can't expire.

Is there any structure that can do both?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `ConcurrentSkipListMap` and iterate the map periodically to purge expired stuff. Since the skiplist is unbounded this opens up a possibility of a memoryleak, when the eviction thread cannot catch up, but in practice this seems very, very unlikely unless you do something extreme.I've also done something like this when I didn't want to use a background thread:

```
static AtomicInteger cnt = new AtomicInteger();

Val put(K key, V val){
    //Do the usual stuff
    if(cnt.getAndIncrement() % 100 == 0){
        //iterate map and evict stuff
    }
}
```

The `if(cnt.getAndIncrement() % 100 == 0)` may have been a "clever optimization", so perhaps you could just iterate and evict everytime like matt b suggests.

Oh just one caveat when you do this.... Be sure to break equality between different entities when the timestamps coincide:

```
class Entity implaments Comparable<Entity>{
    static AtomicInteger SEQ = new AtomicInteger();
    int id = SEQ.getAndIncrement();
    long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int compareTo(Entity other){
        // compare by timestamp
        // If timestamps are equal, don't just return 0 yet!!
        // Compare by id and return 0 ONLY IF the id equals.
        // Otherwise entities disappear from your ordered map and 
        // it's really annoying to debug.
}
```

Comment: i'm using UUID as key, i think i'm fine with 0 :)

Comment: Btw the whole reason that i'm going with map is that UUID. I can have multiple events pushed to multiple streams (desired structure that i'm looking foor) and i want to be able to do a fast query by UUID from different streams. If i were to use some LinkedList i would have to iterate all active streams to find UUID in List item, but with a map i can quickly do a query vs bunch of streams and get events from same origin quite fast.

Comment: @kodisha: Oh so you don't order the map by timestamp? Out of curiosity, why would you want to order the map by UUID?

Comment: Yes, i order by timestamp, but timestamp is not the key, key is UUID. Timestamp is property of object stored in the map.

Comment: @kodisha: I see. Just was curious how you'd use an map that is ordered by UUID (in alphabetic order or something I presume?)...

Answer (score 1):

Extend java.util.LinkedHashMap and override removeEldestEntry() to do whatever you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have very specific and unusual requirements. You'll probably have to write it yourself.

Comment: what i'm basically trying to do is to have time bounded structure. For example i want to have structure that will keep stream of data for 60 seconds, and then expire them automatically. Ordering is crucial feature, because I need to plot incoming events. Righ now i'm storing timestamps, and sorting values in a List before i print them back via API.

Comment: Yep, you'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: The crucial detail is whether the timestamps of the incoming events are not monotonically increasing, because if they did, you would be able to use a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ordered Map (I'm assuming the ordering is based on timestamp), then whenever you add or get items from the Map, you can simply scan from the least ordered value in the Map to the current timestamp - 60 seconds and remove any that fall short. The ordered property of the Map means you don't need to scan the full list on every operation.

Comment: No, that implies that the ordering is the timestamp. It's not clear that this is the case. The order of the items in the map may well not be timestamp order.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use two ordered maps? One is keyed by timestamp and is used to find expired events. The other is keyed by UUID and is used to find events. When removing expired events, use the UUID of the event to remove from the second map.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an ordered view of the concurrent expiring map. You could build one from `ForwardingMap`